# How to run puppeteer tests using Firefox?

Tags: javascript, testing, puppeteer

My puppeteer version is 5.5.0

All the tests are running fine with chrome.

Here is the function I am using to launch the instance.

```js
    async ensure_browser() {
        if (this.browser === null) {
            const {window_size} = this;
            this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                product: 'firefox',
                args: [
                    `--window-size=${window_size.width},${window_size.height}`,
                    "--no-sandbox",
                    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                ],
                defaultViewport: {width: 1280, height: 1024},
                headless: true,
            });
        }
    }
```

I have ran 
`PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install` and
`PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn add puppeteer`

but it still shows this error,

```sh
(node:122450) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find browser revision latest. Run "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install" or "PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox yarn install" to download a supported Firefox browser binary.
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to have a fresh install for puppeteer after removing the node modules folder and then running the following commands:

1. `npm config set puppeteer_product=firefox`
2. `npm install puppeteer`

Then you can use the above code to launch the firefox browser.
Note:: I have tried running it in the same project as chrome and it did not work so I had a fresh setup created for firefox nightly with puppeteer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Akash.
But I already solved it by reinstalling the puppeteer 